# How are transitive dependencies installed in pip?

Tags: python, pip

I have two packages packageA and packageB. packageA depends on packageB.

B has an unmodeled dependency on requests. I discovered this setting up a new environment. I modified the requirements file in /project/packageA of packageB so that it had a direct dependency on requests. Then I ran

```
cd /project/packageA
pip install -e /project/packageB
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

My intuition was that should have installed requests. However, in order to install requests I had to directly add it to /project/packageA/requirements.txt

What's the right way to test this?

Comment: This is confusing, but listing a dependency in a requirements file is different from listing a dependency in setup.py. See [here](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/requirements/) and [here](https://caremad.io/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/).

Comment: Okay, that answers my question. It seems overcomplicated compared to Gemfiles I'm used to in Ruby-land but I think understand now.

Comment: You mean something similar to what "maven" does?

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html